# How can I disable the mouseover behavior of AnimatedImage objects?

Tags: graphics, functions, animation, options

The otherwise very convenient function AnimatedImage displays a "pause" icon when you mouse over its output. Is there an option or trick to disable this? I see that in the documentation it is marked 'experimental', so perhaps there is not yet.

Comment: try if this works for you: `removePlayPauseButtons =  RawBoxes @* ReplaceAll[PaneBox[DynamicBox[___], ___] -> ""] @* ToBoxes;` Then use `removePlayPauseButtons @ AnimatedImage[stuff]`